# How to use global variables in FunctionCompile?

Tags: compile, function-compile, compiler

In `FunctionCompile`, system does not recognize external functions and external global variables by default. But we can use `KernelFunction` to call external function. However, I cannot find any method to use variables or arrays in kernel. Is it possible to use them?

Comment: Pass them as an argument to the function why not

Answer (score 3):

It seems like it is possible:

```
$numberOfWeekDaysInAYear = 260; (* global variable *)
annualise[days_] := days/$numberOfWeekDaysInAYear;

annualiseC =
  FunctionCompile[
   Function[
    Typed[days, "MachineInteger"],
    Typed[KernelFunction[annualise], {"MachineInteger"} -> "MachineInteger"][days]
    ]
   ];
annualiseC[120] (*6/13*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Such as you have a global variables `a`:

```
a = 7;
```

You can use it in `FunctionCompile` with a `With` like this:

```
cf = With[{avalue = a}, FunctionCompile[
   Function[Typed[arg, "MachineInteger"], arg + avalue]]]
cf[20]
```

> `27`